# Use Visual Basic or PHP / SQL? (Need Advice)

Tags: php, sql, vb.net

I need to know if I should create this project as a Visual Basic Windows Application or if I should make it in PHP/SQL.

[Form http://s13.postimage.org/mhpqbp43r/jobs.jpg](http://s13.postimage.org/mhpqbp43r/jobs.jpg)

Basically I'm trying to use this application (or web form) to edit an HTML table filled with job data.

So if I add a new job listing through a private .php form or VB.NET app it will appear in the HTML in my website.

Btw, I'm new to VB.net, PHP and SQL.

Please let me know the easiest way to complete this project. I'm just looking for some general advice please.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: for everyones benefit a real url: http://s13.postimage.org/mhpqbp43r/jobs.jpg

Comment: looks like php would be more suited for this

Comment: Use whatever platform you are most comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

if you are comfortable in vb you can stay on it, thats also a great language with huge capabilities. Its your opinion in which you are comfortable,but if you are beginner

Switch to PHP, both languages have capability to built a form but mostly web developers uses PHP. PHP can make stuff very easy with SQL while in vb its get a little difficult. 
I cannot talk about their pros and cons here as its not allowed. So swithch over PHP without even thinking twice - if you want to become good developer  you should adopt it because for web developer PHP really matters in their future